# Python reading lines ERROR: Invalid query

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an INI with 2 lines in.

```
Discord.exe
steam.exe
```

This is the code I wrote

```
import subprocess

with open("settings.ini") as f:
    for line in f:
        subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", line])
```

This is the output:

```
ERROR: Invalid query
ERROR: The process "steam.exe" not found.
```

How do I fix "ERROR: Invalid query"?

Edit: I only need help with the 1st error, I didn't have steam opened when I tested it

Comment: wrap in try except

Comment: Start steam.exe first.

Comment: Maybe it could be a problem of trailing whitespaces? Have you tried to `subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", line.rstrip()])` to clear them?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this line

subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", line])

with this

subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", line.rstrip()])